# depth in nodes of the same label in custom query

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have in my database `Company` with:

```
@Relationship(type = "COLLECTS_FROM")
private Set<Company> subCompanies
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to create two queries:

- get the company with limited depth 2 for nodes of the same type (so company which collects from different companies, which collects from different companies)
- get the company with full depth for nodes of the same type (similar to previous, but just all the way down without any limitations.

I had a few attempts to solve this and here are those:

- first approach was to use `findById(ID,2)` and `findById(ID,999999)`, but this query has a huge performance drop and I ran into StackOverflow exception, that's why I'm trying to create my own methods similar to what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488427/why-is-findoneid-depth-getting-unacceptably-slow-performance-when-adding).
- second approach was to use custom query (which were actually working in case of different node types):

```
    @Query("Match (company:Company {name:$name})-[relation:COLLECTS_FROM*0..2]->(secondCompany:Company) RETURN company,relation,secondCompany")
    Company customerWithCustomDepth(String name);
```

Unfortunately while using the same node types I ran into the `IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected at most 1` and when I changed return type to the list 3 records were returned (actually the first one of them is what I would like to get, but it seems like specifying `secondCompany` in the return statement populates nodes that I don't want to have in my return type.

- on the third approach I did similar to the second, but it also returned 3 rows (the first one is what I wanted).

```
@Query("Match p = (company:Company {name:$name})-[relation:COLLECTS_FROM*0..2]->(secondCompany:Company) RETURN p")
```

- and fourth one once again 3 companies, instead of a single one (the first one is what I wanted)

```
@Query("MATCH (company:Company {name:$name} ) WITH company MATCH p=(company)-[COLLECTS_FROM*0..2]->(m) RETURN p")
```

And that's basically it. I feel like I'm close, but a little detail is missing. Maybe instead of trying to fix the query, I should somehow limit the result to get the first row from the Query? Any help will be really appreciated.

**update after receiving @cybersam answer:**

The general purpose of this query is to create a tree graph, that's why I would like to get a company with their sub-companies inside (and companies in the sub-companies), not only the parent one.

I could use second, or third approach and just grab the first element on the server side:

```
result.stream()
.findFirst()
.orElseThrow();
```

but I believe it should be able to do it on the service side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the `Company` with the specified `name` if it is connected by a path of 1 to 2 `COLLECTS_FROM` relationships to descendant `Company` nodes:

```
@Query("MATCH p=(c:Company {name:$name})-[:COLLECTS_FROM*..2]->(:Company) WHERE ALL(n IN NODES(p) WHERE 'Company' IN LABELS(n)) RETURN c")
Company customerWithCustomDepth(String name);
```

I assume that you do not want to get a result if there are no such descendants, which is why the [variable-length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) pattern does not use `*0..2`.

*Note: If you want to test for paths of exactly length 2, change `..2` to just `2`.*

The corresponding query for paths of *any* length can be obtained by just changing `..2` to `..`. However, variable-length relationship pattern with no upper bound are not recommended, since they can take "forever" to run or run out of memory.

Comment: Hey @cybersam, thanks for the response, but it seems like we misunderstood a little bit, as I would like to get all companies (not only the parent one) and in your result, the sub-collector size equals 0. The general purpose of this query is to create a tree graph.